# Python Writing output to file in directory

Tags: python

At the moment I have a piece of code that writes the output from previous lines into a .html file in the same location as where the .py file is at....

I am looking for a line of code where it will simply write into the folder ./output/ of the same location the .py file is located

Below is the code I have but cant seem get it to work...

```
fullhtml = '<html><body><pre><h1>%s</h1><h2>#KCBB</h2><table>%s</table></pre></body></html>'%(end_date,myhtml)

with open('%s KCBB Bands.html'%end_date, 'w') as f:
    f.write(fullhtml)
```

Comment: "where it will simply write into the folder ./output/ of the same location the .py file is located" Well, what did you try?

Comment: This code writes to the current working directory which is only the .py directory if you happen to be its directory.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. Please [edit] to clarify what you tried and what exactly the problem is. See [mre] for reference.

Comment: @wjandrea btw is there some command I can use on SO to get that boilerplate? or is everyone else just copying-and-pasting it?

Comment: @Karl I'm using the [shorthand links](/editing-help#comment-formatting): `[tour]`, `[ask]`, `[edit]`, and `[mre]`. Apart from that, I copy-paste the text, but tailor it a bit to each user.

Comment: @Karl btw two shorthands not mentioned are `[es.so]` for [es.so] and `[ru.so]` for [ru.so]

Answer (score 0):

it usually writes it to that location, however, you can use [`__file__`](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-script-file-path/) to refer to that location.

Answer (score 0):

__file__ will give you the python file root.

```
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the filename of your script is in `__file__` (unless you are running in an IDE like jupyter). You can just use it with functions in the `os` module to get that path you want.

```
import os

fullhtml = '<html><body><pre><h1>%s</h1><h2>#KCBB</h2><table>%s</table></pre></body></html>'%(end_date,myhtml)

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "output", 
    '%s KCBB Bands.html' % end_date)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(fullhtml)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i managed to figure it out....

Replacing

```
with open('%s KCBB Bands.html'%end_date, 'w') as f:
```

With

```
with open('./output/%s - KCBB Signal Output.html'%end_date, 'w') as f:
```

Notice the ./output/ < thats the directory i wanted the files to go into.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here,too.  I think you're trying to keep your output files in a subdirectory of the working directory where the .py files are, is that right?  If so, I think you just need to include the folder name in the open statement like so:

```
with open('output/%s KCBB Bands.html'%end_date, 'w') as f:
    f.write(fullhtml)
```

The folder must already exist though, or you'll get an exception.

Comment: It's possible that the current working directory is not the same as the directory containing the .py files.